# qwc2 Label attribute

Tags: labeling

I need to show a label attribute on a QWc2 map. As an example, I need to label points with their ID or polygons with their areas.
I am not able to do the proper configuration or coding.

How can I solve this or can share a sample code for a similar case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing a project of your own using qwc2 you can create and edit the label in the QGIS project, using QGIS. The labels you'll be shown in theweb page.